# SQL update all but one record in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
|f_key1|f_key_2|bool_value|updated_at|
```

I want to write an SQL query which gets every record where bool_value is true and grouped by f_key1 and f_key2 set bool_value to false. In other words, by the end of the query there should only be one record for each pair of the 2 keys where bool_value is true and the rest are set to false. The exact record which is left true does not matter but if it is needed, `updated_at` can be sorted on and the most recent value selected.

Sample data

```
|f_key1|f_key_2|bool_value|updated_at|
|1     |2      | true     | date     |
|1     |2      | true     | date     |
|4     |2      | true     | date     |
```

Output

```
|f_key1|f_key_2|bool_value|updated_at|
|1     |2      | true     | date     |
|1     |2      | false    | date     |
|4     |2      | true     | date     |
```

How would this be achieved in a way compatible with Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: could you please provide your sample data and expected output in table format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f_key1, f_key_2 ORDER BY updated_at DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE bool_value = 1
)

UPDATE cte
SET bool_value = 0
WHERE rn > 1;
```

This approach would leave the most recent record per group with its `bool_value` set to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
update  x1
set     
    bool_value = 1

from    table x1

inner join 
        (
            select  f_key1, f_key2, max_updated_at = max(updated_at)
            from    table x2
            group by 
                    f_key1, 
                    f_key2
        ) x2
on      x1.f_key1 = x2._fkey1
        x1.f_key2 = x2.f_key2
and     x1.updated_at = x2.max_updated_at
```

There you go.